# Pass string variable from expl3 to a command

Tags: expl3

This works (doesn't need anything further, loading the package and that code works perfectly fine, ofc it's just copy-paste from glossaries-extra documentation after all):

```
\glsxtrnewglslike[hyper={false}]{idx.}{\idx}{\idxpl}{\Idx}{\Idxpl}%
```

My question now is: When I have let's say `idx` stored in a string-variable `\str_new:...` (if that's nonesense, and I should normally use a different type of variable than asume that one) how do I do the same like above? I don't want to write `idx.`, `\idx`, and so on, what I want is something that does this automatically with the stored value in the string-variable.

Similar to something along those lines (xparse):

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\Test}{m}{
    \glsxtrnewglslike[hyper={false}]{#1.}{\idx}{\idxpl}{\Idx}{\Idxpl}%
}
```

With this `\Test{idx}` would obviously do the same as my first code. But what I want is that all that stuff `{\idx}{\idxpl}{\Idx}{\Idxpl}` too is somehow replaced with '`#1`+however I do this' so that I can use `\Test{...}` multiple times for different glossaries etc. And ofc I don't want it with `#1` and the `\NewDocumentCommand` (was just an example), rather with a string-variable where `idx` is stored (or whatever one would use here) from the `expl3` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{glossaries-extra}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \yumina_gls_from_str:n #1
  { \exp_args:Ne \__yumina_gls_from_str_aux:n { \tl_to_str:n {#1} } }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \yumina_gls_from_str:n { V }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__yumina_gls_from_str_aux:n #1
  {
    % the group is necessary to not let the build macros to `\relax`
    \group_begin:
    \exp_args:Nncccc \use:n { \group_end: \glsxtrnewglslike[hyper=false]{#1.} }
      { #1 }
      { #1pl }
      { \char_uppercase:N #1 }
      { \char_uppercase:N #1pl }
  }
\exp_args_generate:n { ncccc }

\str_new:N \l_yumina_tmp_str
\str_set:Nn \l_yumina_tmp_str {idx}
\yumina_gls_from_str:V \l_yumina_tmp_str

% or shorter:
\yumina_gls_from_str:n { etc }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Some document doing stuff.
\end{document}
```

---

Explanations:

- `\exp_args:N...` expands the arguments of a function before that function sees them, the different expansion types used here are:

  - `n` do nothing, just a normal argument in braces
  - `e` fully expand things (used on `\tl_to_str:n` that will turn its argument into a string, which can't expand further)
  - `c` build a control sequence name from the contents of the argument (kind-of-fully expanding on the way, but our argument is a string, so just turn that into a control sequence name)
- `\char_uppercase:N` will turn the first character in the string to its upper-case form
- `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` will create a version of a macro that can expand its arguments, we use:

  - `V` get the contents of a variable (as an `n`-type argument, so in braces)
- `\exp_args_generate:n` builds a new `\exp_args:N...` variant from the argument.
- the stringification in `\yumina_gls_from_str:n` is used because it gets an `n`-type argument, probably some user provided code that's not necessarily a string. The fact that we use it on the contents of a string variable isn't known at this point, that's just added later on by `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` (and could in theory also get the contents of a token list variable, or an int, or a dimen, ...).

Comment: can you explain what this `\cs_new_protected:Npn \yumina_gls_from_str:n #1
  { \exp_args:Ne \__yumina_gls_from_str_aux:n { \tl_to_str:n {#1} } }` part does? And first of all ofc thank you <3, it works exactly as I wanted it to. :D

Comment: ... sure, it's bad practice for people to just post code and no explanation (I'd rather answers with explanation and no code)... but you can also just read up `\cs_new_protected`, `\tl_to_str`, `exp_args` documentation in interface3. @Yumina弓那Nirvalen (the gist is to construct the cs token from the cs name using c-type argument)

Comment: @user202729 (without having opened the documentation now -- will do it) does this mean that if `idx` would have already been stored in a list of tokens this line would be 'useless' so to say? :D

Comment: @Yumina弓那Nirvalen ??? you mean "stored in a token list variable"?

Comment: @user202729 yes. I understand what `\cs_new_protected` and `\tl_to_str` does, but the `\exp_args` things I don't quite get tbh ^^.

Comment: @Yumina弓那Nirvalen Actually, in this case it's a str rather than a token list variable, but yes it looks like that it's just a cast "to be sure".

Comment: @Yumina弓那Nirvalen ... after reading the documentation? Sure maybe that one can be hard to understand. (basically `\exp_args:Ne \__yumina_gls_from_str_aux:n { \tl_to_str:n {#1} }` is equivalent to `\__yumina_gls_from_str_aux:e { \tl_to_str:n {#1} }` after the appropriate `\cs_generate_variant:Nn`.

Comment: @user202729 First of all thank you. I will try to read the part about `\exp_args` and so on tomorrow (it's late here) and see if I can understand these parts better. Overall it 'looks' pretty easy ^^.

Comment: @user202729 Okey I think I got it. Still one last question: If this whole thing here would be inside a `\NewDocumentCommand` (idx would be given as `m`-type argument, xparse) than just writing `\__yumina_gls_from_str_aux:n {#1}` would skip this whole part with that expansion `\exp_args:Ne` and `\yumina_gls_from_str:n`, or would I still need it (if yes why)?

Comment: @user202729 it was in the middle of the night and I was tired -> no explanations.

Comment: @Yumina弓那Nirvalen you could use `\NewDocumentCommand \yuminagls { m } { \yumina_gls_from_str:n {#1} }` don't skip the stringification of user-provided arguments if you intend to work on strings. Otherwise the argument might further expand (if that's intended behaviour then, yes, you could leave out the `\tl_to_str:n`).

Comment: Thank you all so much. Now I understand that code completely. Will help me in other areas too <3.